# MySQL combine multiple selects from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have a load of static data that I need to get and at the moment I am creating multiple calls for each table.

To try and increase performance is there a way of doing this in one call?

Sort of like

```
((select * from table1) table1Data,
 (select * from table2) table2Data,
 (select * from table3) table3Data) as staticData
```

Comment: if all of your table have same column count, you can use union..

Comment: Can you show your table structure ?

Comment: All the tables have ID, Name and Type columns and half of them also have a comment column